# I get an http-500 when content type is */*

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, content-type

I could use some help understanding the error that I get. I have an endpoint that works perfectly, but whenever I add a header `Content-Type: */*` I get a `http-500 System error`. I can't understand why. What I managed to find is that the application crashes on creating a self reference link. What could be the problem?

The endpoint that I'm calling:

```
@GetMapping("/public/v1/payment-initiations/{paymentId}")
@PreAuthorize("hasActiveContract() and hasAccessToContract(#contractBeingUsed) and #contractBeingUsed.usesPaymentService")
public PaymentFileStatusDTO getPaymentFileStatus(
        @PathVariable String paymentId,
        @ModelAttribute("contractBeingUsed") Contract contractBeingUsed
) {
    Payment payment = getPaymentAndCheckAccess(contractBeingUsed, paymentId);
    return toDTO(payment);
}
```

And the part where it crashes:

```
PaymentFileStatusDTO paymentFileStatusDTO = new PaymentFileStatusDTO(
            payment.getUuid().toString(),
            payment.getStatus(),
            payment.getErrorCode(),
            payment.getErrorMessage()
    );

    //it crashes here
    paymentFileStatusDTO.add(
            HubsControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(
                    HubsControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn(PaymentController.class)
                            .getPaymentFileStatus(payment.getUuid().toString(), null)
            ).withSelfRel()
    );
```

Comment: So you're sending `Content-Type: */*` with your request? Surely that doesn't make sense. That may be a valid value for the `Accept` header. Sending `*/*` as content type is kinda saying *the content I'm sending you is of whatever type*

Comment: @ernest_k to be honest, it doesn't make any sense to me either, just got a task to fix it. Is there a way I could somehow prevent the http-500? Or somehow restrict it?

Comment: I don't know spring well, but most frameworks give you a way to map the method to an incoming content type, which will enable a framework to return a *client* error (http 415, I think) when an unexpected content type is received. Otherwise, I guess you should be able to read the `Content-Type` header from your request and programmatically validate in your code (sending a 4xx error back to the client in the case of `*/*` or other unexpected content types)

Comment: @ernest_k got it, thanks for quick response!